# check if any item in string list A is a substring of an item in string list B

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to sort through a set of matchers and a set of strings such that if I have

`matchers = ['foo', 'bar', 'abc']`

and

`strings = ['afooa', 'zbarz', 'abcabc', 'purple', 'foobar']`

I'd like to be able to get any element of `strings` where any element of `matchers` is a substring, such that

`results = ['afooa', 'zbarz', 'abcabc', 'foobar']`, ideally without just resorting to nested for-loops.

I've looked around for a while, but this is kind of a hard question to frame in searchable terms, so even any advice on the search front that anybody has would be much appreciated.

Comment: "ideally without just resorting to nested for-loops" Why not? Because it's ugly and you think that there should be a cleaner, shorter way (as in a nested list comprehension), or is performance a problem, and you are looking for a faster approach, maybe something with search trees or the like?

Comment: You could create a regular expression to match `foo|bar|abc`

Comment: Reopened this because there are multiple fundamentally different approaches to the problem (for example the regex-based one). However, I'm pretty sure there's a more specific duplicate lying around somewhere, I just don't really want to try to find it right now.

Answer (score 7):

```
results = [s for s in strings if any(m in s for m in matchers)]
```

Explanation: We iterate through `strings` and add the element if any element from `matchers` is contained the `strings` element.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) (RegEx) if you don't want to code loops:

```
>>> import re

>>> regex = re.compile('|'.join(matchers))
```

This creates a [RegEx](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects) `foo|bar|abc` which will match any of those.

We can use regex's `search` method along with `filter`:

```
>>> list(filter(pattern.search, strings))
['afooa', 'zbarz', 'abcabc', 'foobar']
```

[`search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search) returns a [`MatchObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject), or `None` if there is no match. So we are filtering out the strings which match something (doesn't matter *what* the match is exactly.)

If we used [`match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match) it would match from the start of the string:

```
>>> list(filter(pattern.match, strings))
['abcabc', 'foobar']
```